# ember.js - render() cannot find template specified by `into:` option

Tags: ember.js

I would love some help on this as I've been trying to get this work for a few hours now. It seems like it should be something easy to do.

I'm trying to create a separate layout within my Ember app. For example sake, there's the public `application.hbs` layout, and a private `admin.hbs` layout.

On my route/admin.js, I have tried to use the `renderTemplate()` function to no avail.

**route/admin-dashboard.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  renderTemplate(){
    this.render('admin-dashboard', {
      into: 'admin'
    });
  }
});
```

**templates/admin.hbs:**
``` 
{{outlet}}
````

When doing this, I get the following error in my console: `Error: Assertion Failed: You attempted to render into 'admin' but it was not found`.

The documentation seems to explain this simply, but it does not seem to match the actual behavior. For convenience, here's the example in the documentation. The key parts are the first parameter, and the **`into`** and **`outlet`** options.

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  renderTemplate(controller, model){
    this.render('posts', {    // the template to render, referenced by name
      into: 'application',    // the template to render into, referenced by name
      outlet: 'anOutletName', // the outlet inside `options.into` to render into.
      controller: 'someControllerName', // the controller to use for this template, referenced by name
      model: model            // the model to set on `options.controller`.
    })
  }
});
```

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.17/classes/Route/methods/render?anchor=render

According to the documentation as well, if **`outlet`** is not passed, it will default to either using `{{outlet}}` or `{{outlet 'main'}}`, so there's no need to specify it explicitly from what I can tell. That said, I have tried specifying it explicitly and, again, to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your router look like? Do you have an `admin` route? Why not use the Admin template? What are you using to authenticate? I have a feeling that this is becoming more complex than it needs to be. Usually, you'll have a template for a route - and that template would behave differently depending on whether the user is authenticated.

Comment: https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Route/methods/renderTemplate?anchor=renderTemplate

Comment: @sheriffderek Yes, I have an `admin` route. The `admin` template will still load into `application.hbs`

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: My understanding of `renderTemplate()` in the route is "render some template other than the one implied by the route name", so if you specify `this.render('admin-dashboard', // ...` then `templates/admin-dashboard` should be rendered *instead of* `templates/admin`, hence the `admin` outlet is nowhere to be found.

To test my hypothesis, you could try rendering `into: 'application'` instead, or do not override `renderTemplate` in your `admin` route and try rendering `into: 'admin'` in a *sub*route of it.